# Parsing byte string into a native scala byte

Tags: scala

I'm trying to parse a string like this into a `List[Byte]`.

Here is the string

```
"0x4e 0x01 0x09"
```

How can you instantiate a byte from a string representation?

Comment: What's the expected output for that example?

Comment: List(0x4e,0x010000000, 0x09)

Comment: That's a `List[Int]`.

Comment: You're right, simplifying the OP to use other data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution using a regex and `parseInt`.

```
def parseBytes(s: String): List[Byte] =
  (raw"\b0x([0-9a-f]{2})\b".r
    .findAllMatchIn(s)
    .map(g => Integer.parseInt(g.group(1), 16).toByte)
    .toList)
```

Test:

```
scala> parseBytes("0x4e 0x01 0x09 0xff")
0: List[Byte] = List(78, 1, 9, -1)
```